# Make an hex color brighter or darker without alpha in android

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

This topic exists for lots of languages, but I did't found a working method for android, so here we go:

Given a HEX color, like the grey "#666666", how can I calculate to get it brighter (#999999, #CCCCCC) or darker (#333333)?

I do not want to use androids alpha channel, like "#33666666", but calculate the actually HEX by a choosing factor.

Comment: Adding the R, G, B value respectively can make the color brighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parse it to a color object with [`parseColor (String colorString)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))
- Convert it to HSV with [`colorToHSV (int color, float[] hsv)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#colorToHSV(int,%20float[]))
- Change the brightness and convert it back to a color object

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect